# is it possible to directly import an enum field in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums, python-import

Let's say I have the following enum:

```
class LineStyle(Enum):
    SOLID = 'solid'
    DASHED = 'dashed'
    DASHDOT = 'dashdot'
    DOTTED = 'dotted'
```

Is it possible to somehow directly import fields from this enum ?

Eg:

```
from mymodule.LineStyle import SOLID, DASHED  # does not work
```

The only workaround I could think of is declaring all enums fields as module variables:

```
class LineStyle(Enum):
    SOLID = 'solid'
    DASHED = 'dashed'
    DASHDOT = 'dashdot'
    DOTTED = 'dotted'

SOLID = LineStyle.SOLID
DASHED = LineStyle.DASHED
DASHDOT = LineStyle.DASHDOT
DOTTED = LineStyle.DOTTED
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this ?

Comment: The import mechanism does not get access to items in classes. So, no.

Comment: May I ask why can't you use them like that `LineStyle.SOLID`? why do you need a separate variable for it?

Comment: It is just for cosmetic reasons/code concision. It is redundant to have stuff such as `plot_some_stuff(color=Color.RED, line_style=LineStyle.DOTTED)` instead of just `plot_some_stuff(color=RED, line_style=DOTTED)`.

Comment: For cosmetics I tend to go with qualified imports, maybe, import Color as C?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No. With `import` can only ever add references in the current namespace pointing to the module object itself, or to the top-level names in the module. Enum values are not top-level names in the module unless you explicitly put them there, like in your workaround.

You *can* automate assigning those names to globals, by adding all information from the [`__members__` attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#iteration) to your module globals:

```
globals().update(LineStyle.__members__)
```

The [`globals()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals) gives you a reference to the namespace of the current module, letting you add names to that namespace dynamically. The `LineStyle.__members__` attribute is a a mapping of name to value (including [aliases](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#duplicating-enum-members-and-values)), so the above adds all names to the global namespace:

```
>>> from enum import Enum
>>> class LineStyle(Enum):
...     SOLID = 'solid'
...     DASHED = 'dashed'
...     DASHDOT = 'dashdot'
...     DOTTED = 'dotted'
...
>>> SOLID
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'SOLID' is not defined
>>> globals().update(LineStyle.__members__)
>>> SOLID
<LineStyle.SOLID: 'solid'>
```

If you don't want aliases included in that, use a `for` loop, iterating over the `LineStyle` object. That only gives you the member objects, from which you can then pull the name:

```
for member in LineStyle:
    globals()[member.name] = member
```

Comment: Generating the fields dynamically kinda defeats the purpose of using Enums in the first place for me, which is to have "pseudo strong typing" / IDE friendly code, so I guess I will just stick with my workaround... Thanks anyway.

Comment: @nicoulaj: sure, but then pay the price of having to repeat yourself. Personally, I'd not make globals at all.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot directly import an `enum` member, but you can use a decorator to auto-add the Enum members to `globals()`, which would then be importable. For example:

```
def global(enum):
    globals().update(enum.__members__)
    return enum


@global
class LineStyle(Enum):
    SOLID = 'solid'
    DASHED = 'dashed'
    DASHDOT = 'dashdot'
    DOTTED = 'dotted'
```